# Get All <li> links using loadmore button

Tags: php, wordpress

Im using this code to get all sub menus but i am currently showing minimum 12 but i want when i click load more it shows remaing all menus

```
function sub_menu_list_short($args) {

    $limit = 0;

    $current_menu = $args['name'];

    $array_menu = wp_get_nav_menu_items($current_menu);
    $menu = array();
    foreach ($array_menu as $m) {
        if (empty($m->menu_item_parent)) {
            $menu[$m->ID] = array();
            $menu[$m->ID]['ID'] = $m->ID;
            $menu[$m->ID]['title'] = $m->title;
            $menu[$m->ID]['url'] = $m->url;
            $menu[$m->ID]['children'] = array();
        }
    }
    $submenu = array();
    foreach ($array_menu as $m) {
        if ($m->menu_item_parent) {
            $submenu[$m->ID] = array();
            $submenu[$m->ID]['ID'] = $m->ID;
            $submenu[$m->ID]['title'] = $m->title;
            $submenu[$m->ID]['url'] = $m->url;
            $menu[$m->menu_item_parent]['children'][$m->ID] = $submenu[$m->ID];
        }
    }

    $submenu = array_merge($submenu);

    $html = '<ul>';

    foreach ($submenu as $key) {
        $html .= '<li class="show-alltime"><a href="'.$key['url'].'">'.$key['title'].'</a></li>';

        if(++$limit >= 12) { break; }
    }

$html .= '<button id="my-id">load more</button>'

    $html .= '</ul>';
    return $html;
}
```

this is my code i want loadmore button after 12 menus

Comment: You should accept answers and upvote them if you want to get replies.